# Querydsl error : package com.querydsl.core.types does not exist

Tags: querydsl

I'm enabling querydsl on IntelliJ, and I've set it up and even built it.

build.gradle file

```java
buildscript {
    ext {
        queryDslVersion = "5.0.0"
    }
}

plugins {
    ...
    id 'com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl' version '1.0.10'
}

...

dependencies {
    ...

    // queryDSL
    implementation "com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:${queryDslVersion}"
    implementation "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:${queryDslVersion}"
    testImplementation 'org.querydsl:querydsl-jpa'
}

...

def querydslDir = "$buildDir/generated/querydsl"

querydsl {
    jpa = true
    querydslSourcesDir = querydslDir
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDir querydslDir
}

compileQuerydsl{
    options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.querydsl
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
    querydsl.extendsFrom compileClasspath
}
```

However, QuerydslConfig does not load from JPAQueryFactory.

config.QuerydslConfig file

```java
import com.querydsl.jpa.impl.JPAQueryFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Configuration
public class QuerydslConfig {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Bean
    public JPAQueryFactory jpaQueryFactory() {
        return new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager);
    }
}
```

[image]

(`import com.There is a problem with querydsl.jpa.impl.JPAQueryFactory;` it does not work)

How can we solve this?

I proceeded the same way referring to the article about JPA querydsl, but such an error occurred.